# How to fetch media from a local folder dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, directory

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm wondering how can I fetch media from a folder in a dynamic way without having to add files to an array in the most simple way as possible. Currently I have the following piece of code working:

```js
let slideshow = {
  container: '#slideshow-container',
  media: [
    "1.jpg", "1.mp4", "2.jpg",
    "3.jpg", "dinowalk.mp4", "dirty.mp4", 
    "dog-with-many-balls.jpeg", "goldiejump.mp4",
    "puppy-snapping.gif", "step.mp4", "tippy.mp4",
    "wag.mp4"
  ],
  folder: 'imgs/',
  autoplay: 'yes',
  endless: 'yes'
}
```

How do I replace the below array with dynamic files from the local folder imgs/

```json
[
  "1.jpg", "1.mp4", "2.jpg",
  "3.jpg", "dinowalk.mp4", "dirty.mp4",
  "dog-with-many-balls.jpeg", "goldiejump.mp4",
  "puppy-snapping.gif", "step.mp4", "tippy.mp4",
  "wag.mp4"
]
```

I tried the following but this does not render any image:

```js
var extensions = {};
extensions["jpg"]=true;
extensions["mp4"]=true;
extensions["pdf"]=true;

var extPattern = /\.([0-9a-z]+)(?:[\?#]|$)/i;

var links = [];
$('a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (typeof href !== 'undefined') {
      var ext = href.match(extPattern)
      if(ext!= null && ext.length >1) {
        if(extensions[ext] != undefined) {
          links.push(href);
        }
      }
    }
});

let slideshow = {
  container: '#slideshow-container',
  media: links,
  folder: 'imgs/',
  autoplay: 'yes',
  endless: 'yes'
}
```

Comment: You cannot access the local filesystem from the browser without user interaction (ie an `input` element which accepts a folder)

Comment: @derpirscher with the first peace of code i currently do I have separate js file. I only want to know how to make the array dynamic

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? List the files of a local directory? As I told you: That's not possible from within the browser for security reasons. (Btw it's "piece of code" not "peace of code" )

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks updated the typo. My URL in my browser looks like: file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pics/slideshow.html. I can currently load the jpg's etc

Comment: It's irrelevant how your url looks like. Yes, the browser can load `file:///...` urls, but you cannot access the local filesystem from javascript ...

Comment: @derpirscher Ok. Do you know an example how to do this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/